# How do I run the msbuild tasks in Albacore against multiple .NET versions?

Tags: build, rake, albacore

I am looking at using rake and albacore to automate the build of a library I have created.  I want to offer the library to those using .NET 2.0, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.  There is nothing special about the code and it should port over just fine.

What I really want is a rake build script that will build the assembly for each platform.  Research looks like it is a matter of setting the ToolsVersion but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Are there any best practices, examples of how to do this?  Or do I need a different build tool?

**Update:**
I was able to get this to work just supplying the command line args in the shell but still haven't got it working with Albacore.

Comment: Hello? Is this answer helpful at all? or have you solved your problem already?

Answer (score 4):

The Albacore msbuild task and related configuration object use some [voodoo](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/blob/dev/lib/albacore/config/msbuildconfig.rb#L25) to automatically find and setup the default MSBuild exe version. It's based on the generic command line task, so it has a `command` parameter.

```
self.command = File.join(get_net_version(netversion), "MSBuild.exe")
```

You can set the command option manually and define many tasks

```
task :build_all_versions => [ :build_net20, :build_net35, :build_net40 ]

msbuild :build_net20 do |msb|
  msb.command = 'C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/msbuild.exe'
end

msbuild :build_net35 do |msb|
  msb.command = 'C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5/msbuild.exe'
end

msbuild :build_net40 do |msb|
  msb.command = 'C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/msbuild.exe'
end
```

Or, you can use the [internal Albacore module/method](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/blob/dev/lib/albacore/config/netversion.rb) to get the `msbuild.exe` path. It defines a private module method, so you'll have to `include` it.

```
include Configuration::NetVersion

msbuild :build_net20 do |msb|
  msb.command = File.join(get_net_version :net20, 'msbuild.exe')
  ...
end
```

And, at this point, I would define tasks dynamically based on the array of .NET version symbols.

```
net_versions = [ :net20, :net35, :net40 ]
build_tasks  = net_versions.map { |ver| "build_#{ver}" }

task :build_all => build_tasks

net_versions.zip(build_tasks) do |ver, task|
    msbuild task do |msb|
      msb.command = File.join(get_net_version ver, 'msbuild.exe')
      # all the other stuff
    end
end
```

---

There are no .NET 3.0 tools, they used .NET 2.0 tools, [apparently](https://github.com/Albacore/albacore/issues/20).

Comment: Thanks this answered the exact same question for me.

Comment: I don't know on which version of albacore this is but this did not work for me. I got the following error "NoMethodError: undefined method 'command' ". So I found some documentation and tried this instead which worked. msb.exe = "C:/Program Files (x86)/MSBuild/14.0/Bin/msbuild.exe"